# Can color cycling be achieved in GDI+?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, gdi+, indexed

Is "color cycling" possible in GDI+ with WinForms?  I'd like the modify one or more colors in the palette of an on screen surface so that whenever the surface is repainted, GDI+ will use the modified colors.

Rather than perform the transformation manually pixel-by-pixel, I hope to use GDI+'s capability to render surfaces using indexed colors.  (8bpp indexed color?)

Is there a (fast) way to do this?

NOTE: I don't want to modify the colors globally throughout the application UI.  Rather, I only need  to cycle colors on one particular control surface.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is tied to 8bpp video mode (256 simultaneous colors from a palette of several million). Since almost nobody runs in that mode these days, you wouldn't be able to do hardware palette-based color cycling.

Depending upon what you're trying to do, there may be simple way to achieve this. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Although, i'm wondering if he had an 8-bit/indexed palette picture rendering onto his surface, could he just adjust its palette and repaint? Maybe that'd work?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the picture will be 8-bit/indexed color with respect to GDI+, but finally rendered however GDI+ wishes.  The idea being that I won't have to manually scan through each pixel to test/modify.  I am relatively sure that the user won't need to be in an old video mode for this to work.

Comment: Say you have painted your image, then you modify the palette, and will redraw. Will you be able to do this smooth without flickering? Check the bottom at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32276284/synchronizing-onpaint-to.aspx for syncing to the vertical refresh.